# Gradient descent stochastic update - Stopping criterion and update rule - Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, stochastic, gradient-descent

My dataset has `m` features and `n` data points. Let `w` be a vector (to be estimated). I'm trying to implement gradient descent with stochastic update method. My minimizing function is `least mean square`.

The update algorithm is shown below:

```
for i = 1 ... n data:
    for t = 1 ... m features:
         w_t = w_t - alpha * (<w>.<x_i> - <y_i>) * x_t
```

where `<x>` is a raw vector of `m` features, `<y>` is a column vector of true labels, and `alpha` is a constant.

My questions:

- Now according to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent), I don't need to go through all data points and I can stop when error is small enough. Is it true?
- I don't understand what should be the stopping criterion here. If anyone can help with this that would be great.
- With this formula - which I used in `for loop` - is it correct? I believe `(<w>.<x_i> - <y_i>) * x_t` is my `∆Q(w)`.

Comment: By not understanding the stopping criteria you mean you don't know why you would have it or something else?

Comment: I mean what should be the stopping criteria?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Now according to wiki, I don't need to go through all data points and I can stop when error is small enough. Is it true?

This is especially true when you have a really huge training set and going through all the data points is so expensive. Then, you would check the convergence criterion after K stochastic updates (i.e. after processing K training examples). While it's possible, it doesn't make much sense to do this with a small training set. Another thing people do is randomizing the order in which training examples are processed to avoid having too many correlated examples in a raw which may result in "fake" convergence.

> I don't understand what should be the stopping criterion here. If anyone can help with this that would be great.

There are a few options. I recommend trying as many of them and deciding based on empirical results.

1. difference in the objective function for the training data is smaller than a threshold.
2. difference in the objective function for held-out data (aka. development data, validation data) is smaller than a threshold. The held-out examples should NOT include any of the examples used for training (i.e. for stochastic updates) nor include any of the examples in the test set used for evaluation.
3. the total absolute difference in parameters w is smaller than a threshold.
4. in 1, 2, and 3 above, instead of specifying a threshold, you could specify a percentage. For example, a reasonable stopping criterion is to stop training when |squared_error(w) - squared_error(previous_w)| < 0.01 * squared_error(previous_w) $$.
5. sometimes, we don't care if we have the optimal parameters. We just want to improve the parameters we originally had. In such case, it's reasonable to preset a number of iterations over the training data and stop after that regardless of whether the objective function actually converged.

> With this formula - which I used in for loop - is it correct? I believe **(w.x_i - y_i) * x_t** is my ∆Q(w).

It should be **2 * (w.x_i - y_i) * x_t** but it's not a big deal given that you're multiplying by the learning rate **alpha** anyway.

Comment: what is an objective function that you mentioned here (1,2)? And didn't get it absolute difference? as W is vector of m features ... what do you mean by that?

Comment: "update rule, which I'm using" that has some problem ... its giving me very very big for some w[t] and very very small for other w[t] (vector w's tth component value)

Comment: The objective function is the function you're trying to minimize (or maximize). In your case it's sum of squared error.

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question: "And didn't get it absolute difference? as W is vector of m features ... what do you mean by that?"

Comment: It's normal to have very big and very small values for some parameters in the w vector if you are not using a regularizer. It's relatively easy to modify your objective function adding an L2 regularization term (which will also change the gradient).

Comment: In order to test that your code doesn't have bugs, I suggest testing it with a tiny data set with a couple features (i.e. the vector w has two elements).

Comment: hey thanks @Ammar, the problem was learning factor - alpha .. I changed it to very low and code works ... now I don't understand my performance (square err) for training set is higher than the testing set err! Expected training set err should be low right?

Comment: ya, you would expect the "average" squared error to be smaller in the training set than in the test set. Are you sure you divide by the number of samples?

Comment: omg thanks @Ammar, for both error computation, I was dividing by num of training set samples. My testset error is too high (training 52 and testing - 97) .. any idea, what should I modify? For convergence, I'm checking J(theta) LMS i.e. J(w) = 1 ∑(hw(xt) − yt)**2 ... if its not changing with some threshold I'm done.

Comment: a common mistake in gradient descent is adding instead of subtracting or vice versa. try multiplying your update rule by (-1) and see if it makes a difference.